# Find Gmail accounts configured on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to query the set of configured email accounts on an iPhone (i.e. Settings, Mail / Contacts / Calendar, Accounts) for all of my Gmail accounts.

How can I do this? Is there an API to access emails or email configuration?

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API access to this information currently.

Comment: And nor should there be. Third party apps shouldn't have access to user account details like that.